# Push 2 arrays after json loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I need to run function "testfun 2 times", for each function I will have a few of names lets say testfun(5, global_user) // output [1,2,4,4,5] and for testfun(7, global_user) // output [9,10,11]
How I can put this 2 arrays in one array after I will run 2 functions?

```
testfun(5, global_user);
testfun(7, global_user);

function testfun(groupId, myUser) {
    var selectStr = "Title";
    var itemsUrl = "https://info.com(" + groupId + ")/users" + "?" + selectStr + "&" + orderbyStr;
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor;
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
         url: itemsUrl,
         method: "GET",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
         success: loadTeamNames,
         error: errorHandler
        }
    );
}

var arr = [];
function loadTeamNames(data){
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
  var results = jsonObject.d.results;
  var hide_groups = false;
  $(results).each(function(){
    var name = $(this)[0].Name; 
  });   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `testFun()` uses asynchronous methods you can't do anything immediately after running it twice without waiting for both instnces to complete. This is accomplished using promises

You could use `$when()` and return a promise from `testFun()`. Will need to move `loadTeamNames` into `testFun` to do it

`$.when()` won't complete until both of the promises are resolved

```
function testfun(groupId, myUser) {

    var defer = $.Deferred();

    var selectStr = "Title";
    var itemsUrl = "https://info.com(" + groupId + ")/users" + "?" + selectStr + "&" + orderbyStr;
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor;
    executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url : itemsUrl,
                method : "GET",
                headers : {"Accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose"},
                success : loadTeamNames,
                error : errorHandler
            }
    );
    function loadTeamNames(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        var hide_groups = false;
        $(results).each(function () {
            var name = $(this)[0].Name;
        });

        // resolve deferred and pass data to be used in `$.when()`
        defer.resolve(results);
    }

    return defer.promise;

}
```

To use

```
$.when(testfun(5, global_user),testfun(7, global_user)).done(function (results1, results2) {

    //do what you need to with arrays results1 & results2

});
```

Add `defer.reject()` in the `errorHandler`

Comment: Thanks but lets say can I do in this way: $.when(testfun(5, global_user),testfun(7, global_user)).done(function () {
    console.log(login_name);
}); i just want an output of all numbers in one array

Comment: looks the same as mine ... isn't it?

Comment: you can also add data to the `resolve()` if you want to pass it to `done()`. Not really clear what you needed to do in question. So pass `results` ... `defer.resolve(results)` and both arrays will be in `done(function(results1, results2){...`

Comment: Ok I try now to put a console.log in the return: $.when(testfun(5, global_user),testfun(7, global_user)).done(function () {

 console.log(login_name);

});  But the problem is that this variable login_name is not global may be or if I put it global after that i have undefind

Comment: I don't know enough of your code to help without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

**With JS**

```
var mergedArray = outputOne.concat(outputTwo);
```

**With JQuery**

```
var mergedArray = $.merge( $.merge( [], outputOne), outputTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `jsonObject.d.results` is an array already, you can just do:

`arr.concat(results)`

This will concatenate your array so far with the new result. Have that code inside of `loadTeamNames` and each run of `testfun` will concatenate the result to your current array. not really sure what you're using all those variables inside of `loadTeamNames` for however.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTeamNames(groupId, myUser) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var selectStr = "$select=Title,LoginName";
    var orderbyStr = "$orderby=Title";
    var itemsUrl = "https://sites.sp.kp.org/pub/qosstgcat/_api/web/SiteGroups/getbyid(" + groupId + ")/users" + "?" + selectStr + "&" + orderbyStr;
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(carootUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url : itemsUrl,
                method : "GET",
                headers : {"Accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose"},
                success : loadTeamNames,
                error : errorHandler
            }
    );
    function loadTeamNames(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;
        var hide_groups = false;
        $(results).each(function(){
         var login_name = $(this)[0].LoginName;
        });
        defer.resolve(results);
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

result

```
$.when(getTeamNames(4, global_user),getTeamNames(185, global_user)).done(function () {
        console.log(results);
});
```